# How to reassess a computed value upon key press?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, vue.js, keyboard-events

I would like to display a different random word from a list upon pressing a key.

The "displaying a random word" part works fine:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    verbs: ['parier', 'coûter', 'couper', 'blesser']
  },
  computed: {
    verb: function() {
      return this.verbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.verbs.length)];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  {{verb}}
</div>
```

I now would like to bind a keypress to the re-computation of `verb`. **How should I do that?**

The documentation on [event handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) suggests using `v-on:keydown` for this - I can add JavaScript (`v-on:keydown="alert()"` for instance) but do not know how to trigger a recalculation of a value (I tried `v-on:keydown="eval(verb)"` but it did not work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed values by design are ideally run once.

[One solution](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1250) mentioned by Vue's creator, Evan, was to attach a global listener on component creation, and then call your method directly.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    verb: '',
    verbs: ['parier', 'coûter', 'couper', 'blesser']
  },
  methods: {
    getRandomVerb: function() {
      this.verb = this.verbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.verbs.length)];
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      window.addEventListener('keydown', this.getRandomVerb)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  {{verb}}
</div>
```

To get the demo to respond correctly, Run the code snippet, then click in the snippet window and begin typing.  Random verbs will be displayed.